# How to download a file from website by using logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

how you doing?

I'm trying to download a excel file from a web site (Specifically DataCamp) in order to use its data into an automatic process, but before to get the file is necessary to sign in on the page. I was thinking that this would be possible with the JSON Query on the HTTP action, but to be honest I don't know where to start (I'm new on Azure).

Comment: Have you looked at using PowerAutomate desktop? It’s free for windows 10 users and above.

Comment: I would not consider Azure logic apps for web ripping, in all honesty. Look at ready-made tools if that is your target.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other ways, e.g. your source is on an SFTP, etc. than using an HTTP Action should work, pass the BODY to your next action (e.g. you might want to persist that on a BLOB if content is binary).

If your content is "readable", e.g. JSON, CSV and want to load for processing, you need to ensure, for large files, that you read it in Chunks to load it completely before processing.

Detailed explanation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#download-content-in-chunks